# Draw Line Graph2D with data

Tags: java, graphics2d

I have some problem with Graphics2D Line Chart with data my data
I'm a rookie with Java
Please 
I may not JFREECHART anymore and I must use Java Geometry Primitive

[Like this a line chart I want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n6oD.png)

sorry for my fluent

Comment: http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart is meant to be a good Java charting library, but I haven't used it myself.

Comment: I may not to use JFreeChart